# What is a good HTML5 practice in regard to font colors inside a single block?

Tags: css, html

font tag is deprecated in HTML5. Let's say I have a paragraph in which I need to have some words in specific colors. While I can still use the deprecated font tag to achieve that, what would be a good and clean CSS solution to that?

Comment: Use span tag across those words and style them with css

Answer (score 1):

You can use `span`

```css
span.blue {
  color: blue;
}

span.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
Here is some text - <span class="blue">this text is </span><span class="red">another color but in the same </span>paragraph
</p>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh7rmef0/2)